# Passing class pointer as an argument in a constructor error

Tags: c++

my_world.hpp

```
Class my_world :: public I_my_world
{  
 public:    
   my_world(hello_world* dev);  
   virtual ~my_world() {};  
   virtual int trees();  
private:  
   hello_world* const p_dev;    
}
```

I_my_world.hpp

```
Class I_my_world  
{  
public:  
   virtual int trees() = 0;  
protected:  
   virtual ~I_my_world() {};  
}
```

I_hello_world.hpp

```
Class I_hello_world  
{  
public:  
   virtual void plant() = 0;  
protected:  
   virtual ~I_hello_world() {};  
}
```

hello_world.hpp

```
Class hello_world : public I_hello_world  
{ 
public:   
   hello_world() = default;  
   virtual ~hello_world() = default;  
   virtual void plant() {};  
}
```

my_world.cpp

```
int my_world::trees()  
{  
   p_dev->plant();  
   return 0;  
}

my_world::my_world(hello_world* dev)  
: p_dev(nullptr)  
{  
    
}
```

new_world.cpp -> inside main

```
hello_world * alpha = new hello_world();
my_world * beta = new my_world(alpha);
int b = beta ->trees();
```

Am I doing anything wrong here? My processor gives shell thread error. I just have this much code so its error is not dependent on any other code.

I want to know if I am doing anything wrong code wise, if it is anything related to the processor, I can check other things.

Comment: "I just have this much code so it's error is not dependent on any other code." I guess you did the #include right ?

Comment: Yes, includes are all okay. I just didn't write in the description here

Comment: I am not facing any issue while doing a build, all issues are while running the code

Comment: Please read [the editing and formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), then [edit] your question to format the code properly. And make sure that your [mcve] doesn't contain any problems unrelated to the one you want to ask about (like having `Class` with upper-case `C`). And if you get build errors, the copy-paste the full and complete error output into the question as well, and add comment in the code on the lines where the errors are reported.

Comment: Please check the formatting of your code in the question, the above is almost unreadable. Also, make sure you actually provide a [mcve] along with the verbatim error it produces. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: And perhaps take some time to refresh read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: `Class` -> `class`? `class` is a keyword but `Class` is just an identifier (and in your case a syntax error).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code certainly looks curious

```
my_world::my_world(hello_world* dev) : p_dev(nullptr)
```

That should be

```
my_world::my_world(hello_world* dev) : p_dev(dev)
```

Because `p_dev` is null, you get a crash here

```
int my_world::trees()
{
   p_dev->plant();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that solved the issue. What is the reason behind that though? Why can't I just keep null? Is it because p_dev is constant? Because if it is not constant I don't even need to put p_dev in constructor

Comment: This is basic C++. If you write `ptr->something` then `ptr` cannot be null. Nothing to do with constants. If you *dereference* a pointer then the pointer must be pointing at something.